# How to remove from a string a dynamic part?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am new be indulgent please :)

I am doing a tag generator with a lot of dynamic values, and here is the final output :

> **1554710490545**:[B@**773c0cef**:{"header":{"eventId":"**c0afad22-6472-4f23-9a5d-1c5e0b48024e**",
>   "tmst":"**1554710490545**","agencyId":"**tazz**","customerId":"**02c**",
>   "type":"EzNavigationHitPayload"},"trackingEzNavHit":
>   {"hitBase":{"hitId":"**8735b582-2be7-4764-ac83-da0e4d2206df**",
>   "ezakusBid":"**a40afeb4-066f-4dc8-9de6-e450facecee9**","tmst":"**1554710490545**",
>   "wid":"**widtest**","cookieOk":true,
>   "userAgent":"**Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36","ipV4":"77.154.199.100**","ezCustom":
>   {"eznode":"**gfnode-001**","version":"**4.0.10**"},"agencyId":"**tazz**","customerId":"**02c**"},
>   "ezVarious":{**"ignore":"STRING_TO_CHECK"**}}}

I would like to keep only this part :

> {"hitId":"8735b582-2be7-4764-ac83-da0e4d2206df",
>   "ezakusBid":"a40afeb4-066f-4dc8-9de6-e450facecee9","tmst":"1554710490545",
>   "wid":"widtest","cookieOk":true,
>   "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36","ipV4":"77.154.199.100","ezCustom":
>   {"eznode":"gfnode-001","version":"4.0.10"},"agencyId":"tazz","customerId":"02c"},
>   "ezVarious":{"ignore":"STRING_TO_CHECK"}}}

All the values in bold are dynamically generated and change each time.
I tried with regular expressions but it seems difficult

Comment: Tell us on what basis you want to exclude the part.

Comment: Just saying, but generating random IDs and not storing them for further navigation in your data model is probably not a very efficient pattern. Using a big regex when you have JSON which could be parsed and simply used only shows that something is wrong.

Comment: Please don't format the JSON output, just post it raw and prettified.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From the first curly brace `{`, everything seems to be a JSON.

So you can get the string after that using

```js
let str = `1554710490545:[B@773c0cef:{"header":{"eventId":"c0afad22-6472-4f23-9a5d-1c5e0b48024e", "tmst":"1554710490545","agencyId":"tazz","customerId":"02c", "type":"EzNavigationHitPayload"},"trackingEzNavHit": {"hitBase":{"hitId":"8735b582-2be7-4764-ac83-da0e4d2206df", "ezakusBid":"a40afeb4-066f-4dc8-9de6-e450facecee9","tmst":"1554710490545", "wid":"widtest","cookieOk":true, "userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36","ipV4":"77.154.199.100","ezCustom": {"eznode":"gfnode-001","version":"4.0.10"},"agencyId":"tazz","customerId":"02c"}, "ezVarious":{"ignore":"STRING_TO_CHECK"}}}`;

let x = str.match(/({.*})/);
console.log(JSON.parse(x[1]).trackingEzNavHit)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is json data. So you can access value by key, which you want. For example,
 first take blank json

```
 let output={}
 output["hintId"]= data.hintId
 output["ezakusBid"] = data.ezakusBid

And you can create new json data as your wish
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to the JSON, then use it, instead of parsing a string...
Here's a dynamic way of accessing the `trackingEzNavHit.hitBase`, if the first keys may differ from time to time.

```js
const json = {
  "1554710490545": {
    "B@773c0cef": {
      "header": {
        "eventId": "c0afad22-6472-4f23-9a5d-1c5e0b48024e",
        "tmst": "1554710490545",
        "agencyId": "tazz",
        "customerId": "02c",
        "type": "EzNavigationHitPayload"
      },
      "trackingEzNavHit": {
        "hitBase": {
          "hitId": "8735b582-2be7-4764-ac83-da0e4d2206df",
          "ezakusBid": "a40afeb4-066f-4dc8-9de6-e450facecee9",
          "tmst": "1554710490545",
          "wid": "widtest",
          "cookieOk": true,
          "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
          "ipV4": "77.154.199.100",
          "ezCustom": {
            "eznode": "gfnode-001",
            "version": "4.0.10"
          },
          "agencyId": "tazz",
          "customerId": "02c"
        },
        "ezVarious": {
          "ignore":"STRING_TO_CHECK"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(json[Object.keys(json)[0]][Object.keys(json[Object.keys(json)[0]])].trackingEzNavHit.hitBase);
```

Comment: *1554710490545:[B@773c0cef* is a single generated encrypted string, not a part of json. why you changed [ to {? you can even check the closing braces to confirm.

Comment: are you sure? to me it looks like two keys, and he's forgotten the first and the last part of the json structure. `tmst` is the same as the first numbers.